# Alert Box not showing up in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I am new to JavaScript and trying to learn it. I just have a text field and want to check if it is empty. I am doing it successfully but now i want to check that if it contains only asterisk (*) in a new JavaScript function! my code is showing the alert box Please help me if i am doing something wrong my code is:

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function Verify(){
                if(!isNameEmpty()){
                    return false;
                }

                if(isNotValidName()==false){
                    return false;
                }
            }

                function isNameEmpty(){
                    var name=document.nicform.name.value;
                    if(name==""){
                        alert("Please Enter Your Name!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                function isNotValidName(){
                    var name=document.nicform.name.value;
                        if(name=="*"){
                            alert("hello star");
                            return false;
                        }
                }

        </script>
        <title>
            NIC FORM EXAMPLE
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="nicform" onsubmit = "return Verify()">
        <table border="1" width="400px">
            <th>
                FILL IN ALL THE FIELDS!
            </th>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name:
                    </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="name" maxlength="10" size="30">
                        </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        Age:
                        </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: You should use `document.getElementById('name')` to get the input. Otherwise, use `document.forms.nicform.elements.name`, but avoid `document.nicform.name`.

Comment: How can you expect onsubmit to do anything without a button?

Comment: not working with a submit and getElement by id as well :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this:

```
var name=document.nicform.name.value;
```

to:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
```

And submit your form with js\a button\etc..

Your code is a little messed up. I didn't fix it..only made it work.
Check this plnkr:

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/1c4ygiSZlfvRJM4PBBqp?p=preview)

Comment: 1. No submit button. 
2. No input for age.
3. th with no tr.
4. js conditions aren't right in the verify function.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to target by ID as mentioned by Amiros.

However, if your form was submitting fine before, perhaps try replacing your JavaScript with this:

```
function Verify(){
    var name=document.nicform.name.value;
    if(name==""){
        alert("Please Enter Your Name!");
    } else if(name=="*"){
        alert("hello star");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i want to use a new method for this :(